# Sculpting grass rather than procedurally producing it

Tags: modeling, sculpting, 3d-printing

I've been using Blender to create 3d models to later print for table top rpgs.  One thing I've noticed is that most figures or set pieces don't have any texture to their base. A figure will be standing on a blank, stout cylinder.

I've made stonework easily enough but I want to create a texture similar to grass or foliage. If anyone knows or any tutorials or suggestions please let me know. The only thing I've found online are youtube videos about procedurally making it with nodes--good for images, but can't 3d print.

If anyone does know a way to convert objects procedurally generated with nodes that'd be a great help too.

Comment: I don't know how fine you want to or can print this, but grass is usually consisting of thin leaves relatively chaotic distributed. So to make it look convincing in a 3D software this is mostly randomly placed so it is possibly intersecting. Hard to clean that up for printing. Maybe using some kind of remeshing?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll give it a try

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try a node Curve to Mesh, and then apply your geometry node modifier in the Modifier Proprieties panel.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'll try it too!